# Redirecting URL with dynamic URI segment in cpanel

Tags: php, html, url, opencart, cpanel

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/index.php?information/adminpanel/<?php echo $id;?>" name="approve"   
 id="approve" ">Approve >></a>
```

When I am redirecting to this url it shows correct id in url but gives page not found error. I am new to cpanel. Please tell me is there any other way I can pass this id or how to route page in cpanel with uri segment.

Comment: try by changing permission of that folder to 755

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing a part in URL unless you have changed the routing in `.htaccess` file somehow.

The right URL should most probably be (if you didn't change anything)

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=information/adminpanel&some_id=<?php echo $id ?>
```

Note that the `controller/action` part should be sent as a part of query string under the variable `route` and that the ID variable has to be a part of query string as well under *you name it* variable that is then obtained from `$_GET['younameit']` in your controller.

The routing in OpenCart is done either via SEO URLs like

```
www.mysite.com/category-slug/sub-category-slug/product-slug
```

or even

```
www.mysite.com/product-slug
```

while these are being translated by `mod_rewrite` rule into

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?_route_=<SEO_URL_PART>
```

or by non-SEO URLs where You need to specify the controller

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=common/home
```

where the default `index()` action of `CommonHomeController` is invoked or even by specifying the concrete action to be invoked as in

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add
```

where the `add()` action of `CheckoutCartController` is invoked. Because of this calling an URL like

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=information/adminpanel/123
```

would lead to trying to invoke the action `123()` within the `InformationAdminpanelController` which most probably does not exist. Instead of this if you call URL

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=information/adminpanel&some_id=123
```

it will be the `index()` action invoked while you can obtain the `some_id` value like this:

```
if (!empty($this->request->get['some_id'])) {
    $some_id = $this->request->get['some_id'];
} else {
    $some_id = 0;
}

if ($some_id) {
    // ...
}
```

Again - all described above is the default OpenCart routing behavior and will apply for your installation as well unless you have changed the `mod_rewrite` rules defined in `.htaccess` file.